# How to manually run a skipped stage in an Azure Devops yaml pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure Devops pipelines is it possible to manually trigger a stage if it was skipped?

We have a pipeline that looks like the following...

[image]

We don't want the `Training` or `Production` stages to run automatically if `Staging` has failed (Current behaviour), but we would like the ability to run either the `Training` or `Production` stage manually if it was skipped.

Is this possible?

The use case for this is if a particular test has failed and no-one is around to fix it. We may still want to make a business decision to deploy to production.

Currently you would have to check in a change that fixes or comments out the test and re-run the pipeline. Usually that's exactly the process you want, but on occasion someone may have written a test that only they know why it's failing and how to fix it and you still want to deploy to production.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following setup:

1. Make Training and Production dependent from the Build step
2. Create an additional stage which just as a "[ManualValidation@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)" task, which is dependent form the Build step
3. Add a [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions) to Training and Production which is true if Staging succeeds or if the Manual Validation succeeds.

yaml for the Manual Validation:

```
- stage: DeploymentValidation
  dependOn: Build
  jobs:
  - job: waitForValidation
    displayName: Wait for external validation  
    pool: server    
    steps:   
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
          instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
          onTimeout: 'reject'
```

yaml for the condition:

```
condition: or(succeeded('Staging'), succeeded('DeploymentValidation'))
```

**In general I would ask myself the following questions:**

- Why are your developers able to merge code which has flaky or failing tests into your release branch?
- Are your developers not able to run the mentioned tests in "staging" within their feature/development branches as well?

In an ideal case during your PR validation the same tests which you also run during staging are run which give your developers the confidence that the current build is really ready for a merge into the release branch. In my opinion finding out during staging that some automated tests are failing due to an artifact by one of the developers is already too late.

Comment: The code snippets are just a draft. Keep my updated if you need more input or have some comments about them.

Comment: We don’t have any other branches besides main. Staging, Production and Training are environments. Any features we might want to exclude are governed by feature toggles. These would be UI E2E tests and because of the size and complexity of the application it’s not possible to run the whole or part of the application locally in order to run these types of tests. Can’t argue with your point about needing to fix the tests - it’s just that we only have one person capable of fixing them at the moment. The Yano you provided looks like it might be useful though. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is a good time then to introduce feature branches and Pull Request reviews to enable merge into your main branch. During your Pull Request validation you can deploy the artifact on a PR stage and run your tests. Thereby, you do not need to run everything locally but provide your developers another testing stage as close to production as possible.